# Tweepy capping at 3182 tweets from a user

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have written a script to get all tweets from a given user and save them to a CSV. However I am noticing that I can only get 3182 tweets from any user supplied to the script. Is there some limit put in place by Twitter? Is there a way to get around this?

As a reference, [here](https://gist.github.com/05a9c20f5702b1adeb6e) is my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Twitter-side limitation. [Per the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline):

> This method can only return up to 3,200 of a user’s most recent Tweets. Native retweets of other statuses by the user is included in this total, regardless of whether include_rts is set to false when requesting this resource.

Tweets beyond this horizon are difficult to find, even through the Twitter website — they will only appear if requested by ID. If you want an archive of all your tweets, use the "Request archive" feature in [the Twitter settings](https://twitter.com/settings/account).

Comment: Ok thanks. I requested an archive a long time ago and have yet to receive it which is why I made this